# How to draw a needle on a custom donut chart and add datapoints to the needle?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm created a custom gauge chart using Chart.js, Laravel and Bootstrap 3, now I'm trying to draw a needle and display the datasets with the needle. Here is what I've done so far and I get the gauge to display, however I can't get the needle to display and I'm not sure how to attach data to the needle. Thank you all in advance.

```js
var oilCanvas = document.getElementById("oilChart");

Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = "Lato";
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 18;

var oilData = {
  labels: [],
  datasets: [{
    data: [35, 35, 35],
    backgroundColor: [
      'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
      'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
      'rgba(63, 191, 63, 0.2)'
    ],

    borderWidth: ""
  }]
};

var chartOptions = {
  rotation: -Math.PI,
  cutoutPercentage: 30,
  circumference: Math.PI,
  legend: {
    position: 'left'
  },
  animation: {
    animateRotate: false,
    animateScale: true
  }
};

function drawNeedle(radius, radianAngle) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("oilChart");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var cw = canvas.offsetWidth;
  var ch = canvas.offsetHeight;
  var cx = cw / 2;
  var cy = ch - (ch / 4);

  ctx.translate(cx, cy);
  ctx.rotate(radianAngle);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, -5);
  ctx.lineTo(radius, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(0, 5);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 76, 0, 0.8)';
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.rotate(-radianAngle);
  ctx.translate(-cx, -cy);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(cx, cy, 7, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fill();
}

var pieChart = new Chart(oilCanvas, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: oilData,
  options: chartOptions
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <canvas id="oilChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: [This](https://github.com/fiefdx/gauge-chart-js) and [this](https://github.com/kluverua/Chartjs-tsgauge) might help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api) that offers a range of hooks that may be used for performing custom code. The `afterDraw` hook may be used to draw the needle directly on the `canvas` through [`CanvasRenderingContext2D`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D).

First we need to define the property `needleValue` inside the dataset.

```
datasets: [{
  data: [35, 35, 35],
  needleValue: 580,
  ...
}],
```

The solution is based on the [code sample](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2874#issuecomment-387219952) provided by [Konstantin S.](https://github.com/knstntn). Please have a look at your amended code below.

```js
new Chart('oilChart', {
  type: 'doughnut',
  plugins: [{
    afterDraw: chart => {
      var needleValue = chart.chart.config.data.datasets[0].needleValue;
      var dataTotal = chart.chart.config.data.datasets[0].data.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
      var angle = Math.PI + (1 / dataTotal * needleValue * Math.PI);
      var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
      var cw = chart.chart.canvas.offsetWidth;
      var ch = chart.chart.canvas.offsetHeight;
      var cx = cw / 2;
      var cy = ch - 6;

      ctx.translate(cx, cy);
      ctx.rotate(angle);
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(0, -3);
      ctx.lineTo(ch - 20, 0);
      ctx.lineTo(0, 3);
      ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.rotate(-angle);
      ctx.translate(-cx, -cy);
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(cx, cy, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.fill();
    }
  }],
  data: {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [{
      data: [35, 35, 35],
      needleValue: 27,
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(63, 191, 63, 0.2)'
      ]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    layout: {
      padding: {
        bottom: 3
      }
    },
    rotation: -Math.PI,
    cutoutPercentage: 30,
    circumference: Math.PI,
    legend: {
      position: 'left'
    },
    animation: {
      animateRotate: false,
      animateScale: true
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="oilChart" height="80"></canvas>
```